# How do I create the triangle as in the given picture?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Triangle
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTJkc.png

I am not able to get the image with my code.
Help.

````
    for (int col=1; col<=size; col++) {
            if(col >=row || col==row)    {
            System.out.print(col );
        }else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, and if you want a bigger or smaller triangle, adjust the value of the variable *numberOfRows*.

```
    Integer numberOfRows = 8;

    for (int i = numberOfRows; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int k = 0; k < numberOfRows - i; k++) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

There are cleaner and better ways of doing this, but that should do the job.

1. The **first loop** takes care of displaying the right amount of rows, iterating through *numberOfRows*.
2. The **second loop** takes care of displaying spaces before each row, according
   to the image. Each row have an increasing amount of spaces before the row starts,
   so for the first one we have zero spaces before, for the second, we have one and so
   on. So the value that increases according to this logic as the i value change, is
   the difference between *numberOfRows and the value i*.
3. The **third loop** takes care of displaying the right amount of numbers in each
   row. The first row should have the same amount of numbers as the number of
   rows. So increasing the row number by one, we'll need to decrease the amount
   of numbers in the current row.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int x = 8;
    int y = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i<=8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <=y; j++) {
            System.out.print("  ");

        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= x; j++) {
            System.out.print(j  + " ");
        }
        x--;
        y++;
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
    for(int j = 2; j <= 9; j++){
        int k = j - i;
        if(k > 0) System.out.print(k + " ");
        else System.out.print("  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

A bit shorter is that (with use of the Ternary Operator)

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
    for(int j = 2; j <= 9; j++){
        int k = j - i;
        System.out.print(k > 0 ? k + " " : "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```